# How to remove a prefix from the name of each column of a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, rename, prefix, alter-table

Having a table named "mytable" in MySQL, which sql commands have I to execute to remove the prefix "example_" from the name of each column of the table without explicitily renaming one-by-one all the column names?

Comment: There is no command to automatically do such a thing. As nissim answer points out, the only way to do that is with explicit ALTER TABLE statements. However, you can use a combination of CONCAT, GROUP_CONCAT in a SELECT against the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables to have MySQL build the queries for you.

Comment: Can You write an example of this combination of statements?

Comment: Unless you need to make this change to a lot of tables or need to make the change repeatedly, it's honestly more work to write code to do it, versus just running `SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable` and then use a text editor to make that into an ALTER TABLE statement with `CHANGE COLUMN` for each column.

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate my comment, you can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to have MySQL construct the query for you; you'll still have to run it separately, but if you have a lot of these operations to perform, it can save a lot of typing and help make sure you don't overlook something (though care should also be taken to examine the results before using them to make sure your filtering conditions do not end up also giving undesirable changes.)

It's been a while since I've had call to do something like this, so there may be typos or other small syntax errors, but it gets the general idea across:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', c.TABLE_NAME, '` '
    , GROUP_CONCAT(
         CONCAT('RENAME COLUMN `', c.COLUMN_NAME, '`'
            , ' TO '
            , '`', SUBSTRING(c.COLUMN_NAME, LEN('example_')), '`'
            ) 
         ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION)
    , ';'
   ) AS alterQuery
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_filtering_criteria
   AND c.COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'example_%'
   AND other_filtering_criteria
GROUP BY c.TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY c.TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
`ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN colname type,
MODIFY COLUMN colname type,
etc..,
etc..;`
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.